# lambert conformal conic alternative projection in PROJ4

Tags: python

what's the difference between Lambert conformal conic projection and Lambert conformal conic alternative projection in PROJ4?

Comment: You might want to ask over on the GIS site - https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sometimes looking in the source is useful - https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/blob/32f3ef47e55c38b0eabb6d781fee3944d3239414/src/projections/lcca.cpp#L3

Comment: Hi, wwii, Thanks for the links. When I look into the source, my gain is that it's better to not use LCCA, and maybe the roundtrip precision of LCCA is better than that of LCC, but little mention about the differences between these two. I will post it on GIS site to see. Thanks.